# Doesn't turn on camera by using OpenCV & arch linux

Tags: c++, opencv

My develop H/W environment is Raspberry Pi2 & VX-1000 camera
My develop S/W environment is Arch linux & c++ & opencv

I could stream on webpage by using mjpg-streamer
with this command `mjpg_streamer -i "./input_uvc.so -d /dev/video0 -n -f 30 -r 320x240" -o "./output_http.so -n -w ./www"`

This run is good. (turns on camera (means turns on led on camera) )
But when I execute the program made by opencv code, it doesn't turn on camera (not turn on led) and the function `cvCaptureFromCAM()` returns `NULL`.

My source code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    char c;
    IplImage* frame;
    CvCapture* capture;

    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);

    if(capture == NULL)
        cout << "Strange!!" << endl;


    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH   , 320);
    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT  , 240);

    bool bLoop = true;

    cout << "Start streaming" << endl;

    while (bLoop){
        cvGrabFrame(capture); // Get a frame from cam
        frame = cvRetrieveFrame(capture, 0); // get a frame from capture
        cvSaveImage("save.jpg", frame); 
        cvWaitKey(33); // wait key input for 33ms

    }

    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    cvDestroyAllWindows();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: please, use opencv's c++ api, not  the deprecated c-one.

Answer (score 0):

Let's change this line:

```
capture = cvCaptureFromCam(-1);
```

To:

```
capture = cvCaptureFromCam(0);
```

This will use the correct index that your video camera is in!

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass `0` as the argument of `cvCaptureFromCAM()` or just simply listen to some connected camera by a loop:

```
CvCapture* capture = NULL;

for(int i = 0; i < 100 && capture == NULL; i++)
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(i);

if(capture == NULL)
    return;
```

Last but not least you should avoid the old C API, because it is deprecated and supported poorly, try to use [`cv::VideoCapture`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-videocapture) class instead.

Comment: Take a look at the condition of for: `i < 100 && capture == NULL`

Comment: apologies, please., did not see it. could you do a short edit ? (so i can remove dv / comments ?)